# Joining on value with everything not included in parenthesis

Tags: sql

I want to join on a fields but ignore anything in parenthesis:

for example John (Brown)
should be joined from another table that contains the value John (Smith)

Joining the two Johns.

What would be a potential approach?

Table A:

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | John (Brown) |

Table B:

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 12 | John (Smith) |

Comment: `where replace(replace(A.[Name],'(',''),')','') = replace(replace(B.[Name],'(',''),')','')` -- its gonna perform pretty badly though.

Comment: Also, you've tagged 2 RDBMS... please only tag the system you want an answer in.

Comment: Doesn't this set of replace functions only remove the parens themselves?  Doesn't the OP want everything between the parens removed?  If this is PostgreSQL you can `regexp_replace(A.[Name],'\([^)]*\),'','g')`, but in SQLServer it's more difficult (because no regexp).

Comment: Thanks @ChrisMaurer this is what I had in mind.
what does the g do?

Comment: Also @ChrisMaurer would it be possible to remove the space before the parenthesis as well or is that too complicated

Comment: I've removed your conflicting tags... feel free to add the correct one back.

Comment: @mike_mussina, the 'g' is a flag that tells regex functions to process all occurrences, not just the first one.  To take out any leading spaces before the paren add a ` *` (space, star) to the beginning of the regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

you can extract only name till before start of the open brace and join between the tables.

I have used `-2` on charindex position assumed that always there is a space before the open brace. Alternatively you can use trim and use `-1` instead of -2.

```
select *
from Tablea a
join tableb b on SUBSTRING(a.Name,1,charindex('(',a.Name)-2) = SUBSTRING(b.Name,1,charindex('(',b.Name)-2)
```